# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OpenVPN and dnsmasq not applied for VPN tunnel

Tags: networking, server, dns, vpn, openvpn

I faced this problem recently. It looks like it is quite common, but every each solution which I found doesn't work - so please don't judge me about starting new threads without research. But in the main topic:

I bough a VPS on `nazwa.pl` and I'm trying to configure it to be my `OpenVPN` and DNS server (for my private projects purpose).
I have running `OpenVPN` which is working there quite fine (except DNS for clients). Also `dnsmasq` works fine locally. But it doesn't apply to the VPN tunnel interface (`tun0`) automatically. When I add DNS server to the `/etc/resolv.conf` manually it work like it should, but manually editing any kind of config file doesn't seems to be a good approach ;).
My question is: what should I change to my config, so the `dnsmasq` + `OpenVPN` will start to apply it's changes to the tun0 interface ?

Server:

- Ubuntu `18.04`
- dnsmasq `2.79` with: `IPv6` `GNU-getopt` `DBus` `i18n` `IDN` `DHCP` `DHCPv6` `no-Lua` `TFTP` `conntrack` `ipset` `auth` `DNSSEC` `loop-detect` `inotify`
- OpenVPN `2.4.4` with `enable_async_push=no` `enable_comp_stub=no` `enable_crypto=yes` `enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes` `enable_debug=yes` `enable_def_auth=yes` `enable_dependency_tracking=no` `enable_dlopen=unknown` `enable_dlopen_self=unknown` `enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown` `enable_fast_install=needless` `enable_fragment=yes` `enable_iproute2=yes` `enable_libtool_lock=yes` `enable_lz4=yes` `enable_lzo=yes` `enable_maintainer_mode=no` `enable_management=yes` `enable_multihome=yes` `enable_pam_dlopen=no` `enable_pedantic=no` `enable_pf=yes` `enable_pkcs11=yes` `enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes` `enable_plugin_down_root=yes` `enable_plugins=yes` `enable_port_share=yes` `enable_selinux=no` `enable_server=yes` `enable_shared=yes` `enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no` `enable_silent_rules=no` `enable_small=no` `enable_static=yes` `enable_strict=no` `enable_strict_options=no` `enable_systemd=yes` `enable_werror=no` `enable_win32_dll=yes` `enable_x509_alt_username=yes` `with_aix_soname=aix` `with_crypto_library=openssl` `with_gnu_ld=yes` `with_mem_check=no` `with_sysroot=no`

And here's my config & log files:

```
/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf:

local 77.55.XXX.XXX
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

---

```
client.ovpn

client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 77.55.XXX.XXX 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
script-security 2
# I have both services on the server 
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down-pre
<ca>
... certs here
```

---

```
dnsmasq.conf:

address=/public-domain.com/77.XXX.XXX.XXX
listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=10.8.0.1
bind-interfaces
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq.hosts
expand-hosts
domain=netps
```

---

```
OpenVPN & dnsmasq server iptables:

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere             multiport dports http,https ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:domain

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain state NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain state NEW
```

---

```
VPN server systemd-resolve --status:

Global
     DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
                  10.8.0.1
                  1.1.1.1
                  8.8.8.8
      DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                  16.172.in-addr.arpa
                  168.192.in-addr.arpa
                  17.172.in-addr.arpa
                  18.172.in-addr.arpa
                  19.172.in-addr.arpa
                  20.172.in-addr.arpa
                  21.172.in-addr.arpa
                  22.172.in-addr.arpa
                  23.172.in-addr.arpa
                  24.172.in-addr.arpa
                  25.172.in-addr.arpa
                  26.172.in-addr.arpa
                  27.172.in-addr.arpa
                  28.172.in-addr.arpa
                  29.172.in-addr.arpa
                  30.172.in-addr.arpa
                  31.172.in-addr.arpa
                  corp
                  d.f.ip6.arpa
                  home
                  internal
                  intranet
                  lan
                  local
                  private
                  test
Link 3 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

---

```
VPN client systemd-resolve --status:

Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
      DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                  16.172.in-addr.arpa
                  168.192.in-addr.arpa
                  17.172.in-addr.arpa
                  18.172.in-addr.arpa
                  19.172.in-addr.arpa
                  20.172.in-addr.arpa
                  21.172.in-addr.arpa
                  22.172.in-addr.arpa
                  23.172.in-addr.arpa
                  24.172.in-addr.arpa
                  25.172.in-addr.arpa
                  26.172.in-addr.arpa
                  27.172.in-addr.arpa
                  28.172.in-addr.arpa
                  29.172.in-addr.arpa
                  30.172.in-addr.arpa
                  31.172.in-addr.arpa
                  corp
                  d.f.ip6.arpa
                  home
                  internal
                  intranet
                  lan
                  local
                  private
                  test

Link 58 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
     DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                  1.0.0.1
      DNS Domain: ~.
```

---

```
Syslog:

Jan  2 14:17:40 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.2, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Jan  2 14:17:40 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.2 -> npsclient/91.90.XXX.XXX:40266
Jan  2 14:17:40 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: MULTI: primary virtual IP for npsclient/91.90.XXX.XXX:40266: 10.8.0.2
Jan  2 14:17:41 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: npsclient/91.90.XXX.XXX:40266 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Jan  2 14:17:41 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: npsclient/91.90.XXX.XXX:40266 SENT CONTROL [npsclient]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1,dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM' (status=1)
Jan  2 14:17:41 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: npsclient/91.90.XXX.XXX:40266 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Jan  2 14:17:41 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: npsclient/91.90.XXX.XXX:40266 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Jan  2 14:17:41 serverXXXXXX openvpn[3053]: npsclient/91.90.XXX.XXX:40266 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
```

---

As you can see in the `syslog` DNS isn't pushed to the client, but this is not a surprise as the `systemd-resolve --status` on the VPN server doesn't  have valid DNS servers for `tun0` interface. I can only guess that the problem is on the `dnsmasq` side, but I don't have any clue where and how to fix that.

**EDIT**
content of `/etc/dnsmasq.hosts`:

```
10.8.0.1 gitlab.netps
```

Answer (score 0):

After few days of more trying and doing a lot of reasearch I found that the key issue here is related to `systemd-resolve` mechanism. In short: it stores every each DNS server responses/status in cache and if anything was wrong during the configuration process, it will just ignore the whole server  :/. The case is described in detail here in this thread https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5755

The only solution which I found for now is to manually edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file ...